# Input field inside jQuery UI submenu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this example: http://jsfiddle.net/VPXjs/137/

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu" style="width: 150px;">
<li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Aberdeen</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Adamsville</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Addyston</a></li>
<li>
<a href="#">Delphi</a>
<ul>
<li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
<li><a href="#">quick search <input type='text' name='foobox' size='5' /></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu();
});
```

How do I make the submenu to not close when I press the input field? Also, it seems like the input field is disabled because I can't even type if I do it fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to bind to the click event of the input, stop propagation on it, then focus on it with:

```
$('input').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).focus();
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VPXjs/141/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to overrun the default action of clicking the LI / a in the jquery UI menu. If not you could set focus to the input on hover like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/VPXjs/142/

```
<ul id="menu" style="width: 150px;">
  <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Aberdeen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adamsville</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Addyston</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Delphi</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
      <li><a class="quickSearch" href="#">quick search <input class="fooboxInput" type='text' name='foobox' size='5' /></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>



  $(function() {
$( "#menu" ).menu();
  $(".quickSearch").hover(function(){
    $(".fooboxInput").focus();
  });


 });
```